# use drawn image for game on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to use this user drawn image for the game that follows - i need it do be smaller and go to the top of the screen so that it can move left and right (to dodge objects). What do I do next?

```
@implementation DrawView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
}
return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
// Drawing code.
CGColorRef yellow = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];
CGColorRef red = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
CGColorRef blue = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];

context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();



// draw tryangle
CGContextBeginPath(context);

// give vertices
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x+10, point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x+10, point.y+10);
   CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y+10);

CGContextClosePath(context);

// fill the path
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, red);
CGContextFillPath(context);
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
point= [touch locationInView:touch.view];
[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 10, 10)];


}

- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: It seems like you have something that will follow the finger. Smaller? It's already pretty small. It's not clear what you want to do next.

Comment: i want the user to draw a picture (person etc.) and then that picture is then minimised and then placed at the top of the screen, and it needs to be able to move left and right etc....

Answer (score 1):

As far as how to create a program that lets the user draw a picture, that's a bigger issue than stackoverflow questions are intended for. But let's assume you have got the user input and represented it as a set of points, colors, etc. You have the right idea to use drawRect to draw that variable content in your view.

However, rather than redraw the content every time they move, just draw the content in the same place in the view and move the whole view. For example instead of drawing a square with corners

(point.x, point.y), (point.x + 10, point.y), (point.x + 10, point.y + 10), (point.x, point.y + 10)

draw a square with corners

(0, 0), (10, 0), (10, 10), (0, 10)

Then in touchesMoved instead of the line with setNeedsDisplay, write

```
self.center = point;
```

Also to make it smaller you can set the transform property of the view. So assume the view naturally draws itself large, the way the user drew it, then to make it much smaller you can write

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
```

That will make it one tenth the size.